# Keeping old recurring events in place when drag and drop is performed? (fullcalendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar

I am working with fullcalendar plugin, and I am trying to move events around with drag and drop. However, I have some requirement about how I want those things to move. I can not move events if they have 'close' status or if they happen to be before today on the calendar. All of this work fine expect for recurring events.

With recurring events, if I move one of those events, it moves all other recurring events together (even those that happened before today). However, I want to make the recurring events that already happened to stay were they are. How can I do this?

For all other events (such as single day event), I just used `eventRender` and checked for status of event and date differences to set `event.editable` to false and `event.disableDragging` to true. However, this seems to now have effect on recurring events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define recurring events in fullcalendar you give all of them the same id. If you drag one it will move all others with the same id. So if you don't want to move the events that already happened, give them a different id.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.As this post might answer the question.But little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank's for the warm welcome :). Certainly you are right and it would be good to add more explanation. But in this case it is difficult to add more because for doing that I would need to know how he renders the events.